# How to integrate a new gem into an Rails app (Redmine)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I have developed a gem which implements some algorithms that we'll use within a deployment of Redmine (Rails 2.3.5).

The gem was scaffolded with jeweler, which creates a Rakefile to generate the `.gemspec` file.

However, when I copied to `vendor/gems` and I run `script/console` I get the following warning:

```
config.gem: Unpacked gem cedrux_algorithms in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
config.gem: Unpacked gem cedrux_algorithms in vendor/gems not in a versioned directory. Giving up.
```

When I run the command `rake gems:refresh_specs`, I get the same messages. How can I properly "install" a gem within the `vendor/gems` in Redmine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is accomplished by unpacking the gems on the `vendor/gems` directory:

```
$ cd RAILS_ROOT/vendor/gems
$ gem unpack the_gem
$ cd ../..
$ rake gems:refresh_specs
```